# Angular: get file path using reactive form(formbuilder)

Tags: angular

I am learning to get form values from link https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms. But file upload is not given there so I modified the code and added file upload option in form and in the component but not getting the path. the output I am getting is

```
{
  "firstName": "p",
  "lastName": "a",
  "photo": "C:\\fakepath\\gorgeous-wallpapers-hd-for-desktop-6.jpg"
}
```

in this i am getting incorrect photo path.

**profile.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-editor',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class ProfileEditorComponent {
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: [''],
    lastName: [''],
    photo: ['']
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  public obj: any;

  updateProfile() {
    this.obj = this.profileForm.value;
  }
}
```

**profile.component.html**

```
<p>
  Form Status: {{obj|json}}
</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <form [formGroup]="profileForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label> First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lastName">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Upload File:</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" formControlName="photo">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateProfile()">Update Name</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think File Inputs are handled this way in Reactive Forms. Ideally what's done is, you listen to the `change` event on a File Input and then either upload it to a server and get a download url from there. Or convert it to a Base64 String.

You can then add it to the Object that you receive as a value for the form.

To convert the Image to Base64, you can do this:

```
...
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <form [formGroup]="profileForm">
      ...
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Upload File:</label>
        <input 
          (change)="onFileSelect($event.target)" 
          type="file" 
          class="form-control">
      </div>
      ...
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And implement the `onFileSelect($event)` method like this:

```
onFileSelect(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.photoUrl = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-file-input-value?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: where to write onFileSelect() method .

Comment: That will go in your `profile.component.ts` I've added a Working StackBlitz Eg. You might want to have a look at it.